# How to call a jquery method after dynamic divs(panel) are created using asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, triggers, panel

1. My asp.net page loads with one text box and one button and no hidden element at this point.
2. On button click it does processing and creates number of divs (Panel) based on result. Divs will have result in them as Pass, Fail, Neutral, etc. **This happens by asp.net asynchronous web service call without any page refresh**
3. Now after the divs are created I want to analyze the content of these divs using jQuery and add particular attributes to those divs. eg Div Background color as Green for Pass, Amber for Neutral etc. Would do more processing as required in future.
4. I can do this in asp.net only, but i want to keep the div highlighting thing separate from asp.net code and jquery will be more suitable for that.
5. (Question) Any suggestion how to trigger the jquery method after those divs are created on the webpage.

*Edit 1: I am trying this, but not working.*

```
$(document).on("create", '[id*="GridComp"]', function () { 
    alert("Created 1");
    // change background color of divs or any other thing
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those divs Id attribute contains "GridComp". Then you can use setInterval method and keep checking the existence of divs. If found then style those divs as per the contained text and clear interval.

```
var intervalId;
$(function(){
    intervalId = setInterval(styleDynamicDivs, 500);
});

function styleDynamicDivs(){

    if($('div[id*="GridComp"]').length > 0){
        clearInterval(intervalId);

        $('div[id*="GridComp"]').each(function(){
            var result = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
            if(result == "pass"){
                $(this).css('background-color', 'Green');
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        });
    }
}​
```

Comment: It really worked. Thumbs Up. :) I am still looking for a solution in javascript/jquery as something like callback method or trigger on dynamic div creation. Till then I will be using this method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (It depends on your jquery version that you are currently using)

```
$("#DIV1").live("EventName", function(){

    //...

});
```

and for raise them up, you can use this :

```
$("#DIV1").trigger("EventName");
```

Comment: What will be the eventname that will trigger jquery. I am trying this but not working. Note that I am using a selector as div names in asp.net are all messed up with clientids. 

`$(document).on("create", '[id*="GridComp"]', function () {`
` alert("Created 1");`
`});`

Comment: it depend on what event you want to trigger , I will update my reply now for this

Comment: I am not sure about event. When div1 is created on page, as soon as it is created/visible, some jquery method will run, like alert for now.

Comment: How you add these DIVs to your DOM ?!

Comment: Using ASP.NET.

- I have one ASP.NET Placeholder (basically a DIV) on page as PlaceHolder1. 

- After I get results from WebService It dynamically creates Div (Panel in asp.net) and attach those panels to Placeholder on page. 

- `PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Panel1);`

 
- Now the .NET part is over and after DIVs appear on page I want jQuery to process them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use your jquery code into `pageLoad()`:

```
function pageLoad(){
//your jquery code is here
}
```

or you can call a javascript function from asp.net codebehind:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "call-your-function", "YourFunctionName();", true);
```

edit: for using `pageLoad()` method into your js file, you have to add **scriptmanager** into your asp.net code just once.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

and then, you can doing anything you want into the `pageLoad(){}` after document ready.

Comment: calling JavaScript from my codebehind will work, but I want to keep all javascript things separate from my c# code.

Comment: just add your asp.net code once:

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>`

for now, you can use `pageLoad()` method into your .js file. 

note: you have to use `pageLoad()` function only once.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing provide one class to these div suppose "abc' is a css class and apply this class to these Div`s. Then check content of these div as follows:

```
 if ($('.divclass').html() != "Pass") 
 {
    $('.divclass').addClass("css class name of Pass");
    //Or
   $('.divclass').css('background-color', 'Green');
 }

 if ($('.divclass').html() != "Fail") 
 {
    $('.divclass').addClass("css class name of Fail");
    //Or
   $('.divclass').css('background-color', 'Red');
 }
```

Comment: but when to check contents of these divs ?

Comment: Agree with Sanjeev, when to trigger these methods. I am looking for a solution to call these methods as soon as those divs appear on page. Since a page load is also not happening i can't call them in document.ready()

Comment: Is there any common attribute being added to those divs say class name?